# Firefox debugger : Stepping over html code

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have this remote html page where i need to debug some javascript errors. I do not have access to the page so i have to resort to FF debugger for this. In there i have a js function being called on the `body` `onLoad` like this:

```
<body onLoad="someFunction();" id="bd" class="fs3 FF" >
```

I somehow want to step over it or replace it with this:

```
<body id="bd" class="fs3 FF" >
```

I suspect `someFunction()` is breaking other onload events since i'm getting the error that it is undefined, which it is. What would be the best way to debug this?

I am fairly new to JS debugging but I have tried setting up breakpoints at this line but they always move into the js code within this document. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I do not have access to it since the website belongs to one of my clients. And he would rather have me debug and suggest him the fix instead of providing access!

Comment: `I have this remote html page where i need to debug some javascript errors. I do not have access to the page` - you wont be able to fix it, so what's the point of debugging it?

Comment: Pause the page before onload executes, remove `onLoad="someFunction();"`.

Comment: *"I suspect someFunction() is breaking other onload events"* No, a broken `onload` attribute doesn't prevent other load callbacks (e.g., hooked up via `addEventListener`) from being called ([proof](http://jsbin.com/rinuyi/)). *"I do not have access to the page"* Huh? If you can't change the page, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are probably right. My asumption might be incorrect. But i still have to get that function out of the way just to make sure it's not the cause of the problem which is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect someFunction() is breaking other onload events

A broken `onload` attribute doesn't prevent other load callbacks (e.g., hooked up via `addEventListener`) from being called ([proof](http://jsbin.com/rinuyi/)). But you've said in the comments you want to be able to eliminate it as a possible cause, so:

If there are any `script` elements on the page at all, you can do this:

1. Find the first `script` element.
2. Find the first line of code in that element (either directly in it, or in the file it refers to).
3. Set a breakpoint on that line.
4. Reload the page, which should trigger the breakpoint.
5. Type this in the console:

   ```
   document.body.onload = null;
   ```
6. Click the resume button to allow the code to run.

That code in #5 will remove the handler that the attribute creates. (It won't remove the attribute, but there's no need to. If you really want to, *add* `document.body.removeAttribute("onload");` to the above.) Since your breakpoint is on the first line of a script, it will get hit before the `load` event fires.

Comment: But won't that remove the onload events for the scripts where i need them?

Comment: @hussain: No, just the one handler attached via the `onload` attribute. There can only be one of the old-fashioned "DOM0" event handlers for any given event on an element. Handlers attached correctly, via `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on old IE) are a separate list. (Which is why this won't change anything, as I pointed out in a comment on the question. But I understand your desire to eliminate that as a possible cause.)

Comment: Now that i think of it, thanks to you, the onload might have nothing to do with the problem im having.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that to me. Rudeness was not my intention earlier though. Sorry if you felt that way :)

Comment: @hussain: No worries, written communication is always imperfect. (Come to that, *communication* is always imperfect.) Good luck with the problem.